# Oracle SQL to roll up counts into ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: how to “group by” over a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483140/oracle-how-to-group-by-over-a-range)

Let's say I have data that looks like this:

```
Item             Count
========         ========
1                123
2                1
3                47
4                117
5                18
6                466
7                202
```

I want to create a query that gives me this:

```
Count Start       Count End        Occurrences
===========       ===========      ===========
0                 100              3
101               200              2
201               300              1
301               400              0
401               500              1
```

Basically, I want to take a bunch of counts and group them into ranges for statistical rollups.  I don't think I'm using the right keywords to find the answer to this.  I am going against Oracle, though if there is an ANSI SQL answer I'd love to have it.

Comment: Voting to close my own question since I found the duplicate...

Comment: Consider deleting your question (requires no votes)

Comment: My understanding is that duplicates are preferable to deletes since people might end up using different keywords and stumble on the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    a.mini,
    a.maxi,
    count(a.item)
from
(
    select
        table.item,
        case (table.counter)
            when counter>=0 and counter<=100 then 0
            when counter>100 and counter<200 then 101
            when ....
        end as mini
        table.item,
        case (table.counter)
            when counter>=0 and counter<=100 then 100
            when counter>100 and counter<200 then 201
            when ....
        end as maxi
    from
        table
) a
group by
    a.mini,
    a.maxi
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using CASE statements. If you want it to be scalable, try having the range in a separate table and use JOIN to count the occurence.